# correct way to find max value with association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations, max

I have the following models:

```
#equipment.rb
class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :odometer_type
  has_many :odometers
end

#odometer.rb
class Odometer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :equipment

  # I am currently doing this to find the last mileage entered (which is wrong too cause I want the mileage from the max date entered)

  def self.current_reading(equipment)
    all.where(:equipment_id => equipment.id).max(:mileage)
  end  
end
```

This looks even worse in the view, like this:

```
= @equipment.odometers.current_reading(@equipment)
```

I am thinking there should be a way better way to do this, but I can't seem to come up with or find anything.  I am honestly not even sure how to search for something like this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the mileage for the last inserted odometer of an equipment you do

```
# assuming autoincrement id
@equipment.odometers.order('odometers.id DESC').limit(1).first.mileage

# assuming created_at column
@equipment.odometers.order('odometers.created_at DESC').limit(1).first.mileage
```

If you want to take the max odometer mileage for an equipment:

```
@equipment.odometers.maximum(:mileage)
```

Because of the `Equipment has_many :odometers` relation, in the above code the `:equipment_id => equipment.id` condition is implicit.

You may want to implement something similar to a [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column), only that insted of taking the count you take the max, to speed up queries.

Comment: The Rails method for finding the max value of a column is now called [maximum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-maximum).

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in your equipment model

```
class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :odometer_type
  has_many :odometers

  def max_milage
    odometers.max(:mileage)
  end
end
```

Then you can access it like `@equipment.max_milage`