# ActiveRecord simple max date from a zero to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

ActiveRecord newbie here, frustrated that what seems like a simple SQL query can't be easily turning into ActiveRecord (probably due to my lack of experience).

I have the following SQL which works:

```
select j.id, j.title, jac.latest from jobs j
  left join (select job_id, max(created_at) latest from job_activity_logs group by job_id) jac
  on j.id = jac.job_id
where j.state = 0
```

...that I want to turn into an ActiveRecord query.

In my Rails model I have the relation defined:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :job_activity_logs
```

and

```
class JobActivityLog < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :job
```

Other solutions use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute, which I don't want to use because I need to build up a query based on querystring params (ugly string concat and SQL injection risks).

How do I achieve the same as my SQL in ActiveRecord?

Comment: Please see if this question helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567175/correct-way-to-find-max-value-with-association-rails

Comment: Unfortunately not @tegon because I need details of the latest record in the select list

Comment: Ok, so why can't you do `Job.first.job_activity_logs` since you've declared the association? That would give all the Activity Logs for that job. Then, to select specific attribute you'd have to do a where. It's kinda had to create a query when you don't really know what the result should be.. but I think this is the query you look for in AR. `Job.select(:id, :title, :latest).where(state: 0).first.job_activity_logs.group_by(&:job_id)`

Comment: A few rails exceptions with that @vlad: `private method 'select'`. I then replace 'first' with 'all' to fix, gives me: `undefined local variable or method job_activity_logs`

Comment: Because JobActivityLog is not a Class method. You have to iterate through Jobs first, in order to be able to call job_activity_logs on a Job. Basically, something like this: ```Job.select(...).all.each { |j| j.job_activity_logs }``` .. etc

Comment: ```Job.select(:id, :title, :latest).where(state: 0).each do |j|
  j.job_activity_logs.group_by(&:job_id).each do |ja|
    ... 
  end
end```

Comment: @DanielSim if you want to add your Database schema, to better understand your tables. That would be helpful.

Comment: The .each do will execute the query once for every job row @vlad, that's not what I'm trying to achieve. Certainly, I'll add the schema now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't going to be as pretty as you're hoping, but at least maybe you can get some injection safety out of it.

First thing, let's convert your query into a simpler `JOIN` instead of the subquery, which ActiveRecord doesn't do well.

```
SELECT j.id, j.title, max(jal.created_at)
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN job_activity_logs jal ON j.id = jal.job_id
WHERE j.state = 0
GROUP BY j.id, j.title;
```

Now we can give ActiveRecord each of those parts.

```
Job
  .joins('LEFT JOIN job_activity_logs ON jobs.id = job_activity_logs.job_id')
  .group('jobs.id', 'jobs.title')
  .where(state: 0)
  .select('jobs.id', 'jobs.title', 'max(job_activity_logs.created_at) latest')
```

That should get you a set of `Job`s with `id`, `title` and `latest` fields filled in.

Depending on the rest of your needs, you might want to check out [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel), which ActiveRecord uses under the hood. It's more expressive at the cost of Rails having simplified common actions.

Comment: uglier than I'd hoped, but prettier than I'd feared :) Thanks... this works well

Comment: I know the feeling :-D